# Using NEON code in Android Studio

Tags: android, neon

I've seen few questions about this subject with no answer.
I was wondering if someone already solved this issue.

I'm trying to write NEON code in the JNI where the Android.mk is NOT custom one.
How do I enable it?
On the other hand if anyone know how to get the source code of gradle that deals with setting the configuration flags and building the make file. (I assumed it is the android plugin but got only the manifest file from the git link).

I Imported hello-jni code and saw that **ARM_NEON** is not defined under any abi filter.
(using custom Android.mk makes it possible to compile and run JNI code with NEON instruction but not to browse the code and debug it in the IDE)

Thanks,
 Guy.